# How to redirect to a "post" in paginate

Tags: laravel

Is there any way to redirect to a `post` that I edited in paginate.

Let's say the `post` that I edited is on page `5` and after I edited, I would like to view it after I press `Submit` on edit site.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you can try to redirect back on your controller function post submit

```
return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'message here');
```